# missing procedure "CheckContentType" from THTTPReqResp - Delphi 11 community edition

Tags: delphi, soap, delphi-11-alexandria

I need some help, actually an info about "CheckContentType". -
Does that procedure exist in the community version:

Embarcadero® Delphi 11 Version 28.0.48361.3236

I tried to use that procedure but looks like this method/procedure doesn't exist in:
Soap.SOAPHTTPTrans.pas

Is that method restricted in the Delphi 11 community edition?

Here my simple code I tried:

```
unit EWSUnit;
interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, services, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Soap.InvokeRegistry, Soap.Rio, Soap.SOAPHTTPClient, Soap.SOAPHTTPTrans,
  Soap.SOAPHTTPDisp, Soap.WebBrokerSOAP, Soap.opconvertoptions, soap.webnode,
  IdBaseComponent, IdCoder, IdCoder3to4, IdCoderMIME, Registry;
```

Here the instance:

```
  TEWS = Class(TComponent)
HTTPReqResp1: THTTPReqResp
```

And here is the error:

```
implementation
constructor TEWS.create(G:G_settings; MB:MB_setting);
begin

HTTPReqResp1.CheckContentType; // here is the error: [dcc32 Error] EWSUnit.pas(286): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'CheckContentType'
```

This is a code part of a working (compiled program) and I need to change something in this application but I can not even start to investigate the whole project as  the compiler (in Delphi 11  community edition, Embarcadero) is pointing to that error saying that 'CheckContentType'  doesn't  exist.

Am I missing some additional import / initializing of other Libs here?
Or the Prozedure:'CheckContentType'  only exists in the "paid / full"  Delphi 11 version from Embarcadero?

thank you for your help.

Comment: CheckContentType is available up to Delphi 10.2, but was removed with 10.3. The code is incorporated in THTTPReqResp.Execute now.

Comment: Danke dir Uwe, Didn't know that - now I have to find - if poss. at all - Delphi 10.2  to download and install. As I have  C# knowledge only, not Delphi, (have assigned task in my company to do that in Delphi ) and don't know how to use this new "execute" replacement in Delphi lang.

Comment: "don't know how to use this new "execute" replacement" - we cannot see the whole code, but you are probably doing that already. If the content type check failed, Execute would have thrown an exception. In general, when fixing a project you should better stay with the same version it has been developed before to avoid incompatibilities.

Comment: Thank you, Uwe, I really appreciate your help. 
Nice to know that there are people who can & will help in case one needs that.
I just asked my boss, and he will organize 10.2 version.
In case I need additional help from you, I will write here but for now many thanks.